# Using Keycode with CKeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, dom-events

I wanted to get the keyCode on `keydown` event in ckeditor. My code looks somewhat like this:

```
    editor.document.on( 'keydown', function(event) {
   var keycode= event.data.keyCode & ~(CKEDITOR.SHIFT | CKEDITOR.CTRL |CKEDITOR.ALT);
  alert('Key:'+keycode);
  
});
```

But it always alerts 0. Can't figure why is it so.?

Also I wanted to use `event.preventDefault()` from jQuery, but I can't figure out how to include jQuery library in my plugin.js file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct code if you want to have fun:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'key', function (evt) {
    var kc = evt.data.keyCode,
        csa = ~(CKEDITOR.CTRL | CKEDITOR.SHIFT | CKEDITOR.ALT);

    console.log(kc, kc & csa);
    // kc & csa is what you need
});
```

Or this if you want to have shorter code:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on( 'keydown', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.data.getKeystroke(), evt.data.getKey());
    // getKey() is exactly what you want
});
```

Regarding preventing default - you don't need jQuery for this. CKEditor is so huge tool it has built-in DOM library. You can find `preventDefault` method in the `evt.data` from the second example.

Comment: Did you face some similar problem like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808029/ckeditor-key-event-not-updating-text-properly